# 6.1.21-v8+ (which is the default kernel for 64bit Raspberry Pi's) - can't find kernel source to build new modules

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, kernel-module, arm64

I'm running a R.Pi4B with a default download of the 64bit o/s as selected by the R.Pi download tool. I end up with `6.1.21-v8+`. All runs fine.

```
$ uname -a
Linux pi-box 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
$ ls -l /lib/modules
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 13 00:20 6.1.21-v8+
$
```

I need to compile a kernel module that's not part of this release. However, `6.1.21-v8+` source doesn't exists anywhere. I've looked. These fail:

```
$ curl -OLR http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_6.1.21-v8+.orig.tar.xz
$ curl -OLR http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_6.1.21.orig.tar.xz
```

However, this release is present:

```
$ curl -OLR http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/linux/linux_6.1.38.orig.tar.xz
```

Just for reference, there is also this release:

```
$ curl -OLR https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-6.1.21.tar.gz
```

So I moved on and build those kernels on the R.Pi4 (hint: `make -j4` is your friend!). The module I want (the Microchip MCP2221 driver called `hid-mcp2221`) is in the source tree so I config'ed this up and built a kernel along with that module. I did this under `6.1.21` and `6.1.38`. Neither will load into the kernel.

```
$ sudo depmod -a 
$ sudo cp drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko  /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/hid/
$ sudo xz -z /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko 
$ sudo depmod -a 
$ sudo modprobe -f hid-mcp2221
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hid_mcp2221': Exec format error
$
```

Running `modprobe` with plenty of `-v`'s simply shows:

```
$ sudo modprobe -fvvvv hid-mcp2221
...
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:750 kmod_module_get_path() name='hid_mcp2221' path='/lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko.xz'
insmod /lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko.xz 
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:750 kmod_module_get_path() name='hid_mcp2221' path='/lib/modules/6.1.21-v8+/kernel/drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko.xz'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'hid_mcp2221': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
...
$
```

However, nothing shows up in `dmesg`. Nada!
I checked the `U` undefined values from `nm -u drivers/hid/hid-mcp2221.ko` against the running kernel and they are all there.

What am I doing wrong? TIA.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in this site (it is about programming stuff), we have a sister site about Unix and Linux (check link on top right icon). Do not use curl. We have many tools to download packages and source packages (and dependencies of that if you want). Possibly the sources are in a different deb repository (e.g. rpi specific, and not in debian)

Comment: Rpi kernel is on GitHub. See https://github.com/raspberrypi